# Как записать элементы массива в файл с сериализацией

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<?php

function array_to_file($arr){
    $file = fopen('array.txt' , 'a');
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        fwrite($file, $value); 
    }
    fclose($file);   
}

$arr = array(1,2,3);
array_to_file($arr);

?>
```

Куда добавить корректно `serialize($arr);`  чтобы запись была с сериализацией?

Comment: а можно кодом пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
function array_to_file($arr){

 $file = fopen('array.txt' , 'a');
 fwrite($file, serialize($arr));
 fclose($file);   
}

$arr = array(1,2,3);
array_to_file($arr);
```

Comment: забыли fwrite($file, serialize($arr)); но только что то много параметров записалось в файл a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;} или всё правильно?

Comment: @Sven ну да, это и есть сериализация, а смысл вам ее записывать ф файл если вы не знаете что это такое?

Comment: я знаю что это. Но смотрю что много данных слишком a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}. А куда в моём коде записать теперь unserialize($arr)   ? после fclose или перед?

Comment: @Sven а зачем его туда записывать?

Comment: ну чтоб прочесть потом данныев нормальном виде снова. Куда нужно вставить unserialize($arr) ?

Comment: всё, разобрался...последние вопросы мои были глупые)